# the positions computed by ms

Tags: python, phylogenetics

I am doing simulations using a program 'ms':

https://snoweye.github.io/phyclust/document/msdoc.pdf

If you look at page 3 of this pdf, it explains the output produced by ms. The line which starts with positions tells us the position of segregating sites. But it is between 0 and 1. My simulation produces a chromosome of length 1.1Mb and I want to divide it into 100kb subwindows each. However, I don't know quite understand how I should determine which segregating site (which is a float number) falls into which sub window.

Can someone explain how this can be done?

Comment: To simulate long sequences, it is preferred to use more recent simulators such as [msprime](https://msprime.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [scrm](https://github.com/scrm/scrm). They are much faster and more user friendly.